# Word for suggesting solutions to a problem before the problem is even well-defined or well-understood

Tags: terminology

This remark was said to me awhile ago, perhaps last year, when I was asking for a help on a programming question on Stack Overflow.

The jist was: `"you are suggesting a solution to a problem before you even understood what the problem is."`

I have noticed that this is a common issue on Stack Overflow, with beginner programmers (like me) trying to suggest a solution to our issue before we even understand the problem we are having, like trying to solve world hunger before we even have the money to do so or the socio-economic knowledge.

What is this word/phrase?

Comment: The phrase [jumping the gun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_the_gun) comes to mind.

Comment: Ready, fire, aim!

Comment: premature evaluation

Comment: The X/Y problem was the example used :).

Comment: Jeremiah 6:14a ESV 'They have healed the wound of my people lightly' (ie not bothered to examine, far less tried to address, the underlying issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One version of the issue it is called the [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

> The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.
>
> That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.

Comment: I think this is the exact analogy that individual used!